# Let string act as file

Tags: python, stream

I am working with a library that wants me to pass it data in the form of a file name.  Then it will open that file and read the data.  I have the data in a string, and I don't want to write it to a file (because I don't want to have to delete it afterwards).

Is there a way I can convert the string to a stream and generate a file name that will allow my library to open my stream and access the contents of my string?

Comment: why not use the tempfile module that is builtin to python?

Comment: If you're using Linux, you might be able to use a named pipe.

Comment: Unless I am missing your point then a tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile is exactly what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import tempfile

fh = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()  # this creates an actual file in the temp directory
fh.write(my_string)  
print fh.name
call_other_thing(fh.name)
fh.close()  # file is now deleted
```

Comment: ehh or just use `fh.flush()` before passing the name ... but yeah

Comment: Was going to say maybe chance flush but is there a guarantee using flush that the data will be written?

Comment: I think so ... its worked every time i had buffer issues :P (not gonna dig up proof though ... but i dont think it returns until the buffer is flushed )

Comment: Yep, was thinking of a disk write, that is me done for the night!

Comment: Can I specify an extension for the file?

Comment: yes of coarse ... though im not sure why you would want to as in original Q you say you dont want a file at all ...

Comment: NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".txt")

Comment: It's true, I didn't need a file.  I needed a file name.  It turns out my library is rejecting file if it doesn't have a recognized extension.